# How can I transform a Power BI table with 2 columns of duplicate information into a table with a single column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerquery

I have a table on Power BI containing 2 columns which give me the same type of information. These are tags assigned to each person.

| Date | Name | Tag 1 | Tag 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/04/2023 | Joe | Happy | Excited |
| 31/05/2023 | Casper | Happy |  |
| 31/05/2023 | Emile | Excited | Happy |

I'd like to create a table with a single Tag column in which the rows are duplicated, with Tag 1 in the first row and Tag 2 in the second. **How can I do this in Power Query Editor?**

What I expect is this:

| Date | Name | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31/04/2023 | Joe | Happy |
| 31/04/2023 | Joe | Excited |
| 31/05/2023 | Casper | Happy |
| 31/05/2023 | Emile | Excited |
| 31/05/2023 | Emile | Happy |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the query editor

[image]

first add a custom column

[image]

then remove `Column2` and `Column3`

[image]

then choose `Expand to New Rows` (blue circle)

[image]

If you want to remove row 4 as well, just filter the blanks away in this column.

Answer (score 2):

Click select the Date and Name columns, right click, unpivot other columns